# Restore Azure Media Services' deleted assets

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-media-services

I wanted to know if it is possible to restore an asset in the Azure Media Services if it is deleted ? I haven't been able to find any officially supported solution for this.

Azure storage supports making backups and then copying back restores the blob. But is it possible to do the same thing in Azure Media Services and get the same assetID and locatorID as the original ones ?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, azure media service does not provide back up and restore the assets in your account. Please refer to this [article](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e71279e6-dc86-40ab-8124-0c7517563f71/azure-media-services-account-backup?forum=MediaServices).

> We currently don't provide an automated solution to backup the data in your media services account. You can query your media services account for the data you wish to back up and then write it in some sort of storage.

This is the [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169396-azure-media-services), you could post your idea to help to improve Azure Media Service.

Answer (score 0):

Correct, we don't provide a backup or restore feature for Azure Media Services at this time.  The storage account that is connected to AMS can be backed up - and you can configure geo-redundant storage as well.

We have some customers that configure multiple AMS accounts in two regions and upload content to both for High Availability if needed. You can easily create Assets and Streaming locators with the same IDs in two regions as well.